# YES... Now what's next?

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

Here are some letter sequences, following a very similar rule. The ordering of the sequences may help you solve the sequences. Good luck!

1.

> Y E S _ _ L _ B J _

2.

> U D T C C S _ _ _ D

4.

> E _ T C _ C S _ N D

---

**P.S.:** All errors are intended. Please comment before you edit. Thanks!

**P.P.S.:** This is my first sequence problem. All constructive feedbacks are welcome.

---

Hints:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These must be

> Initial letters of names of numbers 1-10 in various languages

1. Y E S _ _ L _ B J _

> Yī, Èr, Sān, **S**ì, **W**ǔ, Liù, **Q**ī, Bā, Jiǔ, **S**hí
>  (Mandarin)

2. U D T C C S _ _ _ D

> uno, dos, tres, cuatro, cinco, seis, **s**iete, **o**cho, **n**ueve, diez
>  (Spanish)

4. E _ T C _ C S _ N D

> ek, **d**o, teen, char, **p**anch, cheh, saat, **a**ath, nao, das
>  (Hindi)

And the irregular numbering, judging particularly from the missing three, most likely refers to

> the language's rank on [the list of "most native speakers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers#Top_languages_by_population); number three on that list is English, which would have been a dead giveaway.

Comment: yep, you've got it. good job! +1+tick!

Comment: Nice find! ${}$